# blender 2.8 renders png with transparency inverted

Tags: transparency

I have a png with transparency, not an alpha channel:

[image]
I have set up my shaders like this tute:
https://www.katsbits.com/codex/alpha/

My object renders the transparency inverted from the texture map (the transparent map region renders opaque, and the tree regions are transparent).
What did I do wrong/how to fix??

I also tried using an explicit alpha channel PNG, and it has the same problem.
Also it doesn't matter which render engine I used them all, they all show the same transparency problem.

Also in EVEE, I have the material Blend Mode = Alpha Blend.  Alpha clipped, hash and blend all render the same.

Thanks

Comment: While it is true that alpha doesn't equal just transparency for associated alpha, PNG can only store unassociated alpha. The alpha channel represents opacity in this case. If you have a PNG with transparency then it has an alpha channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha channel can be plugged into the alpha socket of the *Principled BSDF* node. If you're using Eevee you will need to set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend*. Then it should display properly and there is no need for a mix shader.

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks!

Comment: @shawn If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: It's kinda ridiculous that this much work is needed to get alpha transparency to display as expected. At the very least, there should be a checkbox to invert the alpha value in the basic options of the material.

Comment: The only thing that had to be done to solve @shawn's problem was to connect the alpha socket of the *Image Texture* node to the alpha socket of the Principled BSDF. How is that a ridiculous amount of work?

Answer (score 0):

OK.  So after poking at this for a while, I come up with the node ordering going into the mix shader affects the transparency.  I had built an alpha channel png, and I was able to get it to work, and when I inverted the mix shader inputs the result was identical to my original post.

So I went back to my original file, swapped the mix shader inputs, and the scene now works as I expect!

Thx
[image]